# Why am I getting "ReferenceError: $cacheFactory is not defined"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cachefactory

When ever I try to run this plunkr code it throws error (see console log).

http://plnkr.co/edit/I0FsK2S30gfNUhlkKwcB?p=preview

I am trying to set `$httpProvider.defaults.cache` here with a default capacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you are not injecting `$cacheFactory` into your config, that is why you are getting 'undefined'. However if you do inject it into your config, your error will change to 'Unknown Provider'. This is because the config section of angular will only accept injected providers.

From here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

```
angular.module('myModule', []).
config(function(injectables) { // provider-injector
    // This is an example of config block.
    // You can have as many of these as you want.
    // You can only inject Providers (not instances)
    // into config blocks.
}).
run(function(injectables) { // instance-injector
    // This is an example of a run block.
    // You can have as many of these as you want.
    // You can only inject instances (not Providers)
    // into run blocks
});
```

Comment: If you know how to workaround this, please detail it here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32545137/set-httpprovider-defaults-cache-in-config-block

Comment: But @Matt Way, I still dont know why this is not working with `$httpProvider`. Any idea why this happens? When there is an option to do this . See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$httpProvider#defaults

Comment: Please read my answer, and then read it again. Firstly this question has nothing to do with `$httpProvider` (your other question is about that). As my answer states, `$cacheFactory` is not a **provider**, and as such you cannot use it in an angular `config()` function. You can still set the `$httpProvider.defaults.cache` though.

Comment: OK. So for further clarifications I will look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32545137/set-httpprovider-defaults-cache-in-config-block .  Thanks @Matt