# Set $httpProvider.defaults.cache in config block

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cachefactory

How can I set `$httpProvider.defaults.cache` in config block in my application?
Whenever I tried I was receiving "ReferenceError: $cacheFactory is not defined" error.

So now, I am trying to find out alternative methods to get this done.

Hence please advice what are the workarounds to achieve this.

Comment: It is not, because I am looking for alternatives

Answer (score 1):

If you read this section on [$http caching](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching), it says:

> You can change the default cache to a new object (built with
>   $cacheFactory) by updating the `$http.defaults.cache` property. All
>   requests who set their cache property to true will now use this cache
>   object.

Notice how you can do it with `$http` instead of `$httpProvider`. The trick is to not set the default cache in config, but rather in a run block, or some other service/factory you have created. For example:

```
app.run(function($http, $cacheFactory){
    $http.defaults.cache = $cacheFactory('myCache', { capacity: 50 });
});
```

---

After reading the docs again, I realised I misread them originally. If you read the docs carefully for the default, it reads:

> defaults.cache - {Object} - an object built with $cacheFactory

This is poorly written, but I think that it means that you pass in the object that you would use to create a cache using `$cacheFactory`. For example:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.cache = { /* your cache config here */ };
```

I believe the provider will utilise `$cacheFactory` behind the scenes rather than you calling it explicitly.

Comment: Alright this is understood. But there is also an option available with `$httpProvider` as well. See, here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$httpProvider#defaults . This is the one that I was trying in the first place but its not working! Why and is there any way how I can make this work using `$httpProvider` itself?

Comment: Thanks @Matt for providing an update. Can you provide a sample? I not sure how we can provide even an object using `$cacheFactory` because its not accessible inside `config` function. And I agree the documentation is not clear enough. Appreciate your help. :)

Comment: My edit shows that you shouldn't use `$cacheFactory` directly in config(), just pass the object you would have used to pass into cache factory. i.e. `default.cache = { your cache info };` instead of `$cacheFactory('somecache', { your cache info });`